# PHP: Autoloading via PSR-4 is saying class not found

Tags: php

I am trying to use a class in my src folder, `DependencyContainer`, but it is saying class not found?

Index:

```
<?php
$dc = new \Mango\DependencyContainer();
```

File structure:

```
src/
    DependencyContainer.php
index.php
composer.json
```

composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "mqwerty/ioc-container",
    "type": "library",
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Mango\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

DependencyContainer class:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace Mango;

class DependencyContainer
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to add the autoload file in your index like this

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

And your `index.php` is going to sth like this

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$dc = new \Mango\DependencyContainer();
```

It will solve your problem

Comment: Why would I need to include the autoload? This project has no dependencies. Including the autoload has nothing to do with PSR-4. I don't even have a vendor folder.

Comment: well @AAA if you dont have a vendor folder then thats a problem, you need to initializ your project first with composer init, you should read the composer docs before askign a question on this

Answer (score 0):

Autoloading doesn't just happen automagically; composer is set up to manage the creation and updating of your PSR autoloading based off the PSR settings of your `composer.json`.

Do a `composer install` in your CLI; that will generate the autoload files in the vendor folder based off of your `composer.json` and create a `composer.lock` file, even if you don't have any dependencies.

From there, you will need to bootstrap the autoload file before executing your code.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve with this answer. I have already generated the autoload vendor class for the main project and I am including it. I am still getting class not found.\

Comment: Are you running the autoload file before execution of your script?

Answer (score 0):

Hey this has already been solved many times but ill still explain just incase you didnt understand others questions.

So I had this problem once too and you can find it on my profile.

psr works based on your path. when you set your src path thats where it starts from,

for example, your layout is something like the following:

```
vendor 
  your-vendor-name
    your-package
      src
        App.php
        Class.php
      composer.json
```

then your psr location should have this after the `:` "/src"

and before it should be something like the following:

"your-vendor-name\your-package\"

when using a class, make sure you composer class names start with an uppercase letter and the class inside matches the file name, make sure the class namespaces are something like this `\your-vendor-name\your-package`

and to use

```php
$app = new \your-vendor-name\your-package\(then the class name you want to use, so lets say, Class.php, then you would put Class() here)
```

hopefully this should solve your problem